# Convert C# Translate Text API code from async to sync for SQL Server CLR function

Tags: c#, sqlclr, microsoft-translator

I have the following code provided from Microsoft to use their Translate Text API. I have registered for the keys and the code works but I can't figure out how to convert this backwards from async/await. Questions are usually asking how to convert code *to* async/await.

I need this to be synchronous is so it can be called from a SQL Server CLR function which I've learned does not support async. I'm guessing I can't use `HttpClient` or `HttpRequestMessage` but I'm going in circles trying to figure this out.

```
    // ***** PERFORM TRANSLATION ON BUTTON CLICK
    private async void TranslateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string textToTranslate = TextToTranslate.Text.Trim();

        // Send translation request
        object[] body = new object[] { new { Text = textToTranslate } };
        var requestBody = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(body);

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage())
        {
            request.Method = HttpMethod.Post;
            request.RequestUri = new Uri("https://api.cognitive.microsofttranslator.com/translate?api-version=3.0&from=en&to=fr");
            request.Content = new StringContent(requestBody, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            request.Headers.Add("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", "00000000");

            var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
            var responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Dictionary<string, List<Dictionary<string, string>>>>>(responseBody);
            var translation = result[0]["translations"][0]["text"];

            // Update the translation field
            TranslatedTextLabel.Content = translation;
         }
     }
```

This is some code from 2013. I'm assuming it worked but the Translator Text API has changed since then. All post requests must be in Json format now and access tokens are no longer mandatory.

```
public static string CallTranslator(string txtToTranslate)
{
    string uri = "http://api.microsofttranslator.com/v2/Http.svc/Translate?text=" + System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(txtToTranslate) + "&from=en&to=fr";
    System.Net.WebRequest translationWebRequest = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(uri);
    string headerValue = GetAccessToken();
    translationWebRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", headerValue);
    System.Net.WebResponse response = null;
    response = translationWebRequest.GetResponse();
    System.IO.Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
    System.Text.Encoding encode = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8");
    System.IO.StreamReader translatedStream = new System.IO.StreamReader(stream, encode);
    System.Xml.XmlDocument xTranslation = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
    xTranslation.LoadXml(translatedStream.ReadToEnd());

    return xTranslation.InnerText;
}
```

Comment: I guess what you need to do is to remove _async_ and _await_ from the code.

Comment: I tried this initially but it seems HttpClient and HttpRequestMessage are async methods. I'm not sure of their sync equivalents.

Answer (score 1):

var response = HttpClientHelper.Instance().SendAsync(request)**.Result;**
var jsonResponse = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()**.Result**;

Comment: please provide comments about what this code does and how it resolves question

Comment: I tried changing:            var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
            var responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();         to:      var response = HttpClientHelper.Instance().SendAsync(request).Result; var jsonResponse = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;        but it wants me to change HttpClientHelper and ends up causing more problems..